# Identity relating hypergeometric function and Legendre polynomial

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function, legendre-polynomials

In my notes I have written down the following relation:

$_2F_1(a,a+\frac{1}{2};c;z)=2^{c-1}z^{(1-c)/2}(1-z)^{-a+(c-1)/2}L_{2a-c}^{1-c}\big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}}\big)\ ,$

where $_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$ is the hypergeometric function and $L_{\alpha}^{\beta}(z)$ is the associated Legendre polynomial. I then use this for the special case $c=1$, reducing to the normal Legendre polynomial.

However now I can't confirm the above identity. I've looked through [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials#Generalization_via_hypergeometric_functions), [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedLegendrePolynomial.html), [Wolfram functions](http://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/LegendreP2/) and [dlfm](http://dlmf.nist.gov/18), to no avail.

Am I missing it in those sites, or did I get it somewhere else? Did I make it up? Does it refer to another function than Legendre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m=1-c$, $n=2a-c$, $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}}$. Then on the left hand side one has
$$
_2F_1(a,a+\frac{1}{2};c;z)=F\left(\frac{n-m+1}{2},\frac{n-m}{2}+1;1-m;1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right),\tag{1}
$$
and on the right hand side:
$$
2^{-m}x^{n-m+1}(x^2-1)^{m/2}{L}^{m}_{n}(x).\tag{2}
$$

Using eq. [(15.8.17)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8) one can write eq. $(1)$ as
$$
x^{n-m+1}F\left(n-m+1,-n-m;1-m,\frac{1-x}{2}\right),
$$
and after using Euler's transformation [(15.1.8)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8) as
$$
x^{n-m+1}\left(\frac{1+x}{2}\right)^{-m}F\left(-n,n+1;1-m,\frac{1-x}{2}\right)=\\
\Gamma(1-m)2^mx^{n-m+1}\frac{(x-1)^{\frac{m}{2}}}{(x+1)^{\frac{3m}{2}}}\cdot \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-m)}\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^{\frac{m}{2}}F\left(-n,n+1;1-m,\frac{1-x}{2}\right).\quad \ (3)
$$

According to Whittaker and Watson the associated Legendre function is given by
$$
P_n^m(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-m)}\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^{m/2}F\left(-n,n+1;1-m;\frac{1-x}{2}\right).
$$

Comparing eqs. $(2)$ and $(3)$ one obtains
$$
{L}^{m}_{n}(x)=\frac{\Gamma(1-m)4^m}{(x+1)^{2m}}P_n^m(x).
$$
When $m=0$ $(c=1)$ one has $L_n^0(x)=P_n(x)$.